# Resampling huge Pandas Dataframe throws ArrayMemoryError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

At work, we have a machine, that is logging some sensor values (e.g. temperatures, pressures, speed, etc.). I have a csv file with these values with somewhat in between 6 and 7 million lines and 13 columns. However, the logger does not write each sensor in each line. Only the first and the last line have a value for each sensor. The lines in between do have a lot of NaN's and the time steps between the lines are not constant. Here are a couple of lines to give you an impression:

```
2017-04-01 00:00:00.000,56.5611838935852,448,80.12215897219313,448,37.12826156616211,448,19.152511596679688,448,6516.885666666667,448,2.9019691567718984,448
2017-04-01 00:00:00.343,,,,,,,,,6517,704,,
2017-04-01 00:00:00.687,,,,,,,,,,,2.9009628295898438,704
2017-04-01 00:00:02.670,,,,,,,19.152511596679688,192,,,,
2017-04-01 00:00:03.343,,,,,,,,,6524,192,,
2017-04-01 00:00:03.453,56.55547332763672,192,,,,,,,,,,
```

We would like to use these values to feed a dynamic simulation to check, if everything runs correctly. The tool we use needs constant time steps and at each step, all values have to be given as an input.

So in order to tackle the problem, I read the csv as a pandas dataframe, resample to 1ms (because the timestamp in the csv has a millisecond accuracy), interpolate the missing values and then resample to 1s, which is the desired time step of our dynamic simulation and to keep the memory and disk space requirements low. No surprise, with this amount of data I am running out of memory already at the step of resampling to 1ms.

I did read the pandas user guide about [Scaling to large datasets](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/scale.html) and had some success. I loaded less columns, used efficient datatypes and used chunking. Only with chunking I was able to process the whole dataframe but it took me about 1.5 hours, which is not acceptable in a productive environment. As the chunks were processed in a for-loop, the processing was serial. I read the part about Dask and thought that parallelizing could speed up the processing, but somehow I am running into memory issues again.

Here is what I tried:

```
raw_df = pandas_df

upsampled_df = raw_df.resample("1ms").asfreq()

dask_df = dask.dataframe.from_pandas(upsampled_df, chunksize=chunk_size)

interpolated_df = dask_df.map_partitions(lambda df: df.interpolate()).compute()

downsampled_df = interpolated_df.resample("1s").asfreq()
```

And here is the error message that is thrown by `upsampled_df = raw_df.resample("1ms").asfreq()`:

> numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 58.6 GiB for an array with shape (7862399001,) and data type int64

The issue is (I think) that I still have to use pandas to resample the dataframe, as Dask does not offer any equivalent to the `asfreq()` function that returns a resampled dataframe. `dask_df.resample("1ms")` does work, but returns a Resampler object, that I cannot interpolate afterwards.

How would you approach this issue? I know that especially in sciences its pretty common to have huge dataframes that need to be processed, but I really couldn't find anything useful on the internet that solves my problem.

And please bear in mind that I am neither a pandas, nor a python pro. So chances are high that I am missing something obvious.

Comment: How about resampling directly from raw_df to "1s" frequency using nearest method, using distance limit condition ? It would avoid the 1ms frequency resampling and the result may be acceptable don't you think ?

Comment: Exactly. Why resample to 1ms?

Answer (score 0):

Resample is time-based groupby, so not necessary to expand the dataframe in the begining, can use an apply to treat the dataframe by chunks (frequency)

If I understand correctly, the error is negligible if we split the data by days when has millisecond accuracy

For example, start a date range of 9 days

```
import pandas as pd
index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=9, freq='D')
series = pd.Series(range(9), index=index)
```

Applied the actual UDF operation on the chunks of each day. For each chunks (days). It will resample to 1ms (lambda function)

```
series.resample('D').apply(lambda x: x.resample('1ms').asfreq().interpolate().resample('1s').asfreq())
```

or 30 minutes

```
series.resample('30T').apply(lambda x: x.resample('1ms').asfreq().interpolate().resample('1s').asfreq())
```

And I do have kernel dead (memory issues) when I try to directly resample to 1ms

`series.resample("1ms").asfreq()`